# How to download a file in a password-protected location in Delphi 2007

Tags: html, delphi, file, download

I need to get the contents of a HTML page from the Web, but the contents of the respective resource is only available after the user has logged into the website.

To be more specific, I need to download the HTML page of a video file that has been flagged as inappropriate on Youtube. I do have the login credentials, but I'm not sure on how to proceed with the login.

I'm currently downloading non-password-protected HTML pages with HTTPSend from Synapse, and I also have a licensed copy of Clever Internet Suite 7 I used in a previous project.

The code I'm using looks like that (this is strictly informative, I can change the approach if necessary):

```
function GetHTMLFile(s: string): string;
var
  sHTTPSource:TStringList;
  HTTP: THTTPSend;
begin
  try
    sHTTPSource := TStringList.Create;
    if HttpGetText(s, sHTTPSource) then
    begin
      result := sHTTPSource.Text;
    end;
  finally
    sHTTPSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I don't expect you to do all the work for me, but I'd really appreciate a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Did you at least try to find out what kind of authentication is being  done? Do you  know what HTTP BASIC authentication is? Or Digest Authentication?  Does a browser-created dialog box come up asking for the user name and password or do you log in using text entry controls that are built into the web page, and are thus handled in code by the web app you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THTTPSend has a property .Cookies (TStringList) which takes name-value pairs (each one being a cookie).  If you use the same THTTPSend instance to post through the login procedure then the cookies sent from YouTube will be captured and will be retained in future requests using the same THTTPSend instance.  You can either do this each time (getting a new cookie) or you can hard (or soft) code the cookie information into the THTTPSend before making the request to the protected page.

You can also just do the login once and save the .cookies TStringList somewhere, each time assigning it to any new THTTPSend you create to make new requests.

Comment: Hey, Justin. Thanks for the input, that's the method I Have considered. However, I've checked the Synapse documentation, but there's nothing about posting the username and password. Do I need to use another component for the login part, "sniff" the cookie and then use it in the next HTTPSend requests?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I re-read TFM again and I figured it. Great piece of advice. Thanks again.