# How to enable cookies using the ararat.cz Synapse library?

Tags: delphi, http, cookies, github

Im trying to post 2 params to github with the synapse lib but it's saying from my log.txt (The Server Response)

```
Cookies must be enabled to use Github
```

So my question is, how to enable cookies using the synapse library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [THTTPSend.Cookies](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.THTTPSend.html#Cookies). From another StackOverflow question - [How to download a file in a password-protected location in Delphi 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554391/how-to-download-a-file-in-a-password-protected-location-in-delphi-2007)

"THTTPSend has a property .Cookies (TStringList) which takes name-value pairs (each one being a cookie)."